# Union operation in spark running very slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'm running a spark sql with below statements and configuration but apparently `dfs.reduce((x, y) => x.union(y)).distinct().coalesce(1)` step is taking a lot of time to execute,roughly 5 mins, my input parquet file has just 88 records. Any thoughts what could be the issue ?

```
   val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .config("spark.serializer", 
   "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  .getOrCreate()

//set new runtime options
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 6)
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
  spark.conf.set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
spark.conf.set("spark.cores.max", "8")

  val dfs = m.map(field => spark.sql(s"select 'DataProfilerStats' as Table_Name, 
    '$field' as Column_Name,min($field) as min_value from parquetDFTable"))

  val withSum = dfs.reduce((x, y) => x.union(y)).distinct().coalesce(1)
```

**UPDATE**

I have a single parquet which I'm reading into dataframe, question is also that if it can be split into smaller chunks.

Comment: what if you omit the `coalesce(1)`? In addition, are you sure  that really this statement is slow, maybe also the way you load your data is slow (lazy execution)

Comment: what is the length of dfs (i.e. how many dataframes are in it?)

Comment: Hi Raphael and Assaf,I have tried removing coalesce, still it was slow.Length of dfs is 10 but even if I just run it with 2 dataframes,it still runs slow,after parsing the sql statement is gets into the long run (as I see it on console)

Comment: what action are you using?

Comment: Hey Assaf, The big sql has min, max, unique_val, collect_list, dense_rank operations plus cast of datatypes.